# How should I refute myself?

Tags: discussion

Supposing that months or years ago I have answered a Question a certain way, but then I gain a change of perspective on that issue and/or I come across information which negates a position that I express in the Answer to said Question, what is our preference for me to refute this previously held position?

Is it better to:

Edit the Answer and input some kind of note indicating that the Answer previously contained a different stance from what it will eventually be saying? E.g. "I thought such-and-such before, I submitted that thought into this Answer, but later on found out I was mistaken, and consequently, here is what I currently have to say on the matter."

Or:

Add a second/alternate Answer explaining that I'm doing this in order to debunk my older Answer to the Question?

Comment: I am a bit pressed for time these days, and I don't know when I'll find time to post a full answer (with references, etc). Quick one, to not let you keep waiting: If you feel the new answer is distinct enough from the old one, post it separately. Editing shouldn't change the intent of a post (even when you it's your own post).

Answer (score 5):

If there is a new insight that could improve a post or make the info reported in that post obsolete, my **personal opinion** is that the wrong information should be either edited out, or even better: marked as obsolete/wrong information (some people put a stripe through the text) and with a clear EDIT: mark notifying that the new knowledge you are sharing makes some of the old answer obsolete.

In some cases the answer that has been given is a mistake people other than the poster make (Chronos and Kronus have been getting confused since antiquity). In this case I think it is better to leave that info on the answer so other people might learn from it.

In the case that the answer you already wrote, in light of the new information is dead wrong my **personal opinion** is that a new answer should be made since the votes or accepted mark does not apply to the new information you are sharing. Implying in this answer of course that your previous answer is wrong.

Again this is my personal opinion and might not reflect how this SE operates.